# error unrecognized arguments : nohup in docker

Tags: docker, nohup

I am running my tests from inside a docker container . List line in Dockerfile is

```
CMD ["nohup","/bin/scripts/run_test.sh","&"]
```

This causes the docker to terminate with the error as below

```
 2022-09-07 16:13:48,626 - sinit - DEBUG - simple_init.py logger configured
    usage: simple_init.py [-h] [-t TIMEOUT] [-v] [-f]
    simple_init.py: error: unrecognized arguments: nohup /bin/scripts/run_test.sh &
```

Putting nohup is necessary for me as this process ends without doing the needful job completely, if I don't put nohup.

The command looks fine to me in general, what might be causing this issue ?

P.S :
As of now I do not have , an ENTRYPOINT , earlier I had same command (without & in the end )configured as ENTRYPOINT , but it does not run the jar inside the container till it performs the desired operation whereas without being contanerized it works as expected , so some where docker is killing the operation earlier than expected.

Comment: `&` is not an argument to `nohup`. It's an instruction _to a shell_, but you have no shell here, so nothing is parsing that instruction; so it's being passed as an argument to `run_test.sh`, which doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Also, in general, trying to daemonize something inside a docker container is not using Docker the way it's designed to be used. You should run your software in the foreground: that is to say, it should just be `CMD ["/bin/scripts/run_test.sh"]`. If you want to start the container in the background, you can do that by adjusting which docker command you use.

Comment: *Putting nohup is necessary for me as this process ends without doing the needful job completely, if I don't put nohup* -- did you observe that to be true _inside Docker_, or is that how the software in question behaves _outside_ Docker? To be clear, even if it's the problem still happens inside Docker, using nohup won't necessarily fix it there, even if it fixed it otherwise.

Comment: (`nohup` isn't magic; it does a very limited set of things, and most of those things Docker itself does anyhow as a matter of course. First, nohup redirects stdin, stdout and stderr away from the terminal; second, it declines to forward HUP signals sent when the terminal that started it closes; Docker itself _also_ redirects stdin, stdout and stderr away from the terminal except when you use `-i` or `-t`, and _also_ doesn't forward HUP signals from when the terminal closes).

Comment: (...even in bash, using nohup is mostly useless; `nohup something &` is almost exactly the same as `something </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 & disown -h "$!"`)

Comment: Charles is spot on with the concerns about nohup. With the command in the background the container would immediately exit, so there are multiple design issues in what's being done here. But importantly, the `simple_init.py` seems to indicate an entrypoint configured in the image, and we'd need to know what that is. Please see [mcve].

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  As of now I do not have , an ENTRYPOINT , earlier I had same command (without & in the end )configured as ENTRYPOINT , but it does not run the jar inside the container till it performs the desired operation whereas without being contanerized it works as expected , so some where docker is killing the operation earlier than expected.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  despite using nohup docker killed the command much earlier than expected.